# Mobile Test Workbench - Status of the RTW server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

I've been testing MTWWW for about a couple of days, and I've come to notice something.
I have to add the device to MTWW by going to a url on the device that looks like this,
protocol://hostname:+port/mobile

However, sometimes my device can't reach that address neither when I restart eclipse. When that happens I typically restart my computer and everything is fine and dandy again.

There was even one time that on that same screen that display the QRCode and URL to add a device, a notification appeared which showed something close to "RTW server could not start properly" or something like that.

This led me to believe that MTWW uses some other web server other that WL server to receive the recordings from the instrumented apps.
This also led me to believe that perhaps sometimes when the server tries to start the ports are already binded to some socket and it fails the initialization. Just speculation here.

However if there is a slight sense in what I written, is there a way to inspect the status of the RTW server, some dashboard perhaps? 
Besides that, what should I do to fix when the RTW server didn't start properly? Rebooting the computer is pretty lame, there must be something more clever to do.

Oh, I've found this behavior on a mac osx box, on a windows one I haven't done so much testing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no dashboard for the server. But if yoy think that the issue come from the port, you can change it in the preferences. Please read http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21678980

Hope its help